# CodeIgniter pagination add search query string to pagination URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I am a beginner in Code-Igniter. My Current pagination URL is like this

```
http://www.sample.loc/admin/users?per_page=2
```

When I search a term this will convert to the following url.

```
http://www.sample.loc/admin/users?user_search=abcd
```

I want to include the search term to the pagination links. So that I can apply pagination on the searched items. ie,

```
http://www.sample.loc/admin/users?per_page=1&user_search=abcd 
or
http://www.sample.loc/admin/users?per_page=2&user_search=abcd
```

Anyone can let me know how I can do this without changes in the existing library? or Should I have to create my own pagination for this system?

My Config File is given below.

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['per_page'] = 5;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$config['num_links'] = 6;

$config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="bg-blue">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['prefix'] = "";
```

Comment: http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/10/codeigniter-pagination-with-search-query-example-bootstrap.html

Answer (score 0):

Add line on your controller

```
    $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

$config['reuse_query_string'] set to be true pagination add get parameter itself.
Example : {domain}/product/index/**100**?category=&subcategory=&searchbyname=natural&filter=

Answer (score -1):

Can bootstrap pagination will work?

```
<?php
class pagination extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->model('pagination_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //pagination settings
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('pagination/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tbl_books');
        $config['per_page'] = "3";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        // integrate bootstrap pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '«';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '»';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        // get books list
        $data['booklist'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books($config["per_page"], $data['page'], NULL);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        // load view
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
    }

    function search()
    {
        // get search string
        $search = ($this->input->post("book_name"))? $this->input->post("book_name") : "NIL";

        $search = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $search;

        // pagination settings
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("pagination/search/$search");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books_count($search);
        $config['per_page'] = "5";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        // integrate bootstrap pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        // get books list
        $data['booklist'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books($config['per_page'], $data['page'], $search);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //load view
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

Now create a file named ‘pagination_model.php’ inside ‘application/models’ folder

```
<?php
class pagination_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //fetch books
    function get_books($limit, $start, $st = NULL)
    {
        if ($st == "NIL") $st = "";
        $sql = "select * from tbl_books where name like '%$st%' limit " . $start . ", " . $limit;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_books_count($st = NULL)
    {
        if ($st == "NIL") $st = "";
        $sql = "select * from tbl_books where name like '%$st%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}
?>
```